# Django - unable to get a foreign key attribute displayed

Tags: python, django, view, foreign-keys

I am writing a Django webapp.

I need some help on why my sidebar is not showing "company.name" which is a foreign key attribute.

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/templates/employee/base.html

```
  <h4>{{ request.user.get_full_name }}</h4> <--- can display
  <h5>{{ request.employee.company.name }}</h5> <--- cannot display
```

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)  <--- this is the foreign key
```

Here you can see the problem, its not showing the "company name" below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sluiy.jpg

Comment: you cant access your model through request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as `request.employee` - you need to go through the user.

```
{{ request.user.employee.company.name }}
```

Comment: but you need a  OneToOne relation between the user and the employee

Comment: thank you so much. that was fast response. accept the answer! in 6 minutes later i can accept accord SO

Comment: onetoone relationship is there @mohammedqudah

Comment: fix pushed to git